# Are “sillage” and “sillon” related?

Tags: étymologie

Je viens d’apprendre le substantif *sillage* et j’y ai noté une similitude avec *sillon*. Les deux signifient un désordre longitudinal qui reste comme rayure ou trace à la surface d’une substance molle après le passage d’un objet rigide — la coque d’un vaisseau sur l’eau et la charrue sur le sol.

Le CNRTL n’indique aucune consanguinité étymologique. Est-ce que mon intuition m’a mis en erreur ? Même si ce n’est que coïncidence, j’en profiterai comme aide-mémoire.

Comment: @None, je j'ai modifié selon ton conseil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon moi ton intuition ne t'a pas trompé. *Sillon* et *sillage* sont apparentés selon le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie* et le  *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*.

***Dictionnaire de l'Académie***

> [SILLON](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9S1660) nom masculin
> Étymologie : XII<sup>e</sup> siècle. Dérivé de l’ancien français *silier*, « labourer », lui-même tiré du gaulois **selj*‑, « amasser la terre ».

et

> [SILLAGE](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9S1656) nom masculin
> Étymologie : XV<sup>e</sup> siècle. Dérivé de *siller I*.

De là donc allons à *siller I* et on est renvoyé à la même étymologie que *sillon*.

> [I. SILLER](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9S1657) conjugaison verbe intransitif
> Étymologie : XV<sup>e</sup> siècle. Dérivé de l’ancien français *silier*, « labourer », lui-même tiré du gaulois **selj*‑, « amasser la terre ».

Le ***Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*** reprend ce parcours et en ajoute un autre possible, les deux arrivant à un lien de parenté entre *sillon* et *sillage*.

> **Sillage** (XV<sup>e</sup> s. *seillage*, *sillage* 1574 ; dér. de l'ancien verbe *siller* « tracer son sillage » (d'un navire) [1484], au fig. 1566, *Siller* représente un emploi figuré de l'anci. franç. *silier* → sillon)

> **Sillon** (1462, Villon, réfection de *seillon* (v. 1200 « mesure [de terre] », sans doute plus ancien d'après le diminutif *seillonet* (v. 1175) ; p.-ê. dér. de l'anc. franç. *silier* « labourer » (1322), issu d'un lat. pop., **seliare*, d'un rad. gaullois **selj*-. Cette hypothèse (retenue par Wartburg) repose sur l'anc. fraç. *seil* « sillon » (v. 1210) et le rhéto-roman *saglia* « bande étroite au milieu d'un pré fauché ». Selon P. Guiraud, *sillon* viendrait du verbe *siller* (1484 *seiller*) « faire un sillage », qu'il rattache au lat. pop. **seculare*, du lat. class. *secare* → scier)

Answer (score 2):

Sauf erreur de ma part, une parentée apparaît bien dans le CNRTL, même si c'est un peu noyé dans le paragraphe :
Il est indiqué que tous deux dérivent d'un même verbe *silier* ou *siller*.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sillon

> Sillon : (...) Dér. de l'anc. verbe silier (**siller***); suff. -on*.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sillage

> Sillage :
> (...)
> Dér. de **siller***; suff. -age*;

d'ailleurs, voici ce que ce même CNRTL donne pour cet ancêtre commun *siller* : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/siller

> Empl. fig. de l'a. fr. silier « labourer avec la charrue » (1322,
> Runk., p. 39) qui survit dans les parlers du Bas-Berry, de l'Yonne et
> du Rouergue (FEW t. 11, p. 416b) et qui continue très prob. un gaul.
> *selj- « amasser la terre », d'où aussi l'a. fr. seil « sillon » (ca 1210, Herbert de Dammartin, Foulque de Candie, éd. O. Schultz-Gora,
> 1998; v. aussi la note de l'éd.) et le rhéto-rom. saglia « bande
> étroite au milieu d'un pré fauché sur laquelle on étend l'herbe du pré
> entier ».